# set cookie when its not checked

Tags: php, jquery

i have these codes and when i run these it set cookie when checkbox is checked and when is unchecked.
in both case it set cookie

```js
$("#login_submit").click(function(){
    var login_username=$('input[name=login_username]').val();
    var login_password=$('input[name=login_password]').val();
    var remember=$("#remember").is(':checked');

    $.ajax({
      url:'includes/login.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:{login_username,login_password,remember},
      success:function(data){
        location.href='controlpanel.php';
      },
    });
  });
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false" class="login-form" action="" method="post">
  <div class="login-container">
    <input type="text" class="modal-login" placeholder="username" name="login_username">
    <input type="password" class="modal-login" placeholder="password" name="login_password" style="margin-bottom:3px">
    <div class="remember-div">
      <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
      <label for="remember">remember me</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="login" name="login_submit" id="login_submit">login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**and php codes**

```html
require_once '../config/config.php';

$login_username=$_POST['login_username'];
$login_password=md5($_POST['login_password']);

$login_check=mysqli_query($db,"select * from users where username='$login_username' and password='$login_password'");
$username_id=mysqli_fetch_array($login_check)['id'];
if(mysqli_num_rows($login_check)>0){
  $_SESSION['login'] = $username_id;
  $remember=$_POST['remember'];
  if($remember){
    setcookie('login',$username_id,time()+60*60*24*30,'/');
  }
  echo "ok";
}else{
  echo 'ko';
}
```

in both cases it set cookie when its cheked and when its not checked

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Don't use MD5 for the hashing of user passwords! it isn't secure! switch to SHA or Bcrypt

Comment: your missing the fields/keys in the post, also login_username is open to SQL injection

Comment: @isaac tanx. i fix it at the end of the project

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone where i missing that ? i got it in this code: $_POST['remember'];

Answer (score 0):

I like to give you a suggestion.

When user clicks on the "Remember me" checkbox, set the cookie. The cookie will be used just to show the credentials next time when they try to login. So they can easily login for the next time.

If they not clicked/checked the "Remember me" checkbox, then don't save the cookie.

For login and user panel management use Sessions. Set session when they login and destroy the session when they logout.

If you need more information, ask me.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have

```
$remember=$_POST['remember'];
if($remember){
    setcookie('login',$username_id,time()+60*60*24*30,'/');
 }
```

'if ($remember)' will always be true as it is just checking for a value not whether that value is actually 'true', just that a value exists, even if the value is 'false'.

There are a few ways to fix this but one way is:

In your HTML add a value to your checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" value="remember">
```

In your javscript change

```
var remember=$("#remember").is(':checked');
```

to

```
var remember= $('#remember:checked').val();
```

Then in your PHP

```
if ($_POST['remember'] == 'remember') { // your code
```

Comment: tnx . now how should i write ?

Comment: @sporal - I've edited my answer with a possible solution.